# Rendering sld style(buffer) SEVERE null java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException

Tags: sld, geotools, rendering

Can somebody help me with this error, it throws it when rendering an object and styling it with use of a buffer (sld style, wkt string). So I suppose that some problem is with buffering but was unable to figure out what is happening to solve it. Buffer values are mostly between -5 and -0.3. Example from sld file is bellow. Is it posible to this happens because of small values of the "Nagib"?

```
SEVERE  null
java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException
    at java.awt.image.DataBufferInt.<init>(DataBufferInt.java:75)
    at java.awt.image.Raster.createPackedRaster(Raster.java:467)
    at java.awt.image.DirectColorModel.createCompatibleWritableRaster(DirectColorModel.java:1032)
    at java.awt.image.BufferedImage.<init>(BufferedImage.java:333)
    at org.geotools.renderer.style.SLDStyleFactory.markToTilableImage(SLDStyleFactory.java:1229)
    at org.geotools.renderer.style.SLDStyleFactory.getTexturePaint(SLDStyleFactory.java:1171)
    at org.geotools.renderer.style.SLDStyleFactory.getPaint(SLDStyleFactory.java:1093)
    at org.geotools.renderer.style.SLDStyleFactory.setPolygonStyleFill(SLDStyleFactory.java:481)
    at org.geotools.renderer.style.SLDStyleFactory.createPolygonStyle(SLDStyleFactory.java:436)
    at org.geotools.renderer.style.SLDStyleFactory.createStyleInternal(SLDStyleFactory.java:375)
    at org.geotools.renderer.style.SLDStyleFactory.createStyle(SLDStyleFactory.java:328)
    at org.geotools.renderer.style.SLDStyleFactory.createStyle(SLDStyleFactory.java:291)
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.processSymbolizers(StreamingRenderer.java:2569)
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.processFeature(StreamingRenderer.java:2453)
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.drawPlain(StreamingRenderer.java:2309)
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.processStylers(StreamingRenderer.java:1930)
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.paint(StreamingRenderer.java:834)
    at org.geotools.swing.RenderingTask.call(RenderingTask.java:106)
    at org.geotools.swing.RenderingTask.call(RenderingTask.java:41)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Example from sld

```
<Rule>
    <Name>Public building</Name>
    <Title>g</Title>
    <ogc:Filter> 
        <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
            <ogc:PropertyName>THEME_ID</ogc:PropertyName>
            <ogc:Literal>729</ogc:Literal> 
        </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo> 
    </ogc:Filter> 
    <PolygonSymbolizer>
        <Geometry>
            <ogc:Function name="buffer">
                <ogc:PropertyName>the_geom</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:PropertyName>Buffer</ogc:PropertyName>
            </ogc:Function>
        </Geometry>  
        <Fill>
            <GraphicFill>
                <Graphic>
                    <Mark>
                        <WellKnownName>wkt://LINESTRING(0 0, ${sin(Nagib - 45) * 20000} ${cos(Nagib - 45) * 20000} )</WellKnownName>
                        <Stroke>
                            <CssParameter name="stroke">
                                <ogc:PropertyName>COLOR</ogc:PropertyName>
                            </CssParameter>
                            <CssParameter name="stroke-width">2.5</CssParameter>
                        </Stroke>
                    </Mark>
                </Graphic>
            </GraphicFill>
        </Fill>
    </PolygonSymbolizer> 
    <LineSymbolizer>
        <Stroke>
            <CssParameter name="stroke">
                <ogc:PropertyName>COLOR</ogc:PropertyName>
            </CssParameter>
            <CssParameter name="stroke-width">1</CssParameter>
        </Stroke>
    </LineSymbolizer>
</Rule>
```

Comment: can you provide a small example dataset

Comment: Here is small example in shp file, in gis2.shp is two objects that I identified to return this error (while exporting for this example), sld is for them. https://www.sendspace.com/delete/968ha5/c6d1b7d958b4cac58af2911296fec612

Comment: that link tries to delete the file

Comment: my bad this is the right link https://www.sendspace.com/file/7ou7fa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually caused by one of your symbols becoming very long (5.464099919557841E8px) which causes the renderer to overflow an integer and incorrectly think it is negative. I've raised a [bug](https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOT-5878?) to improve the error message but it isn't actually a bug as there is no way for the renderer to draw this symbol.

If all you actually want is a rotated hatch I think you could just use a rotation element, something like:

```
<PolygonSymbolizer>
    <Geometry>
        <ogc:Function name="buffer">
            <ogc:PropertyName>the_geom</ogc:PropertyName>
            <ogc:PropertyName>Buffer</ogc:PropertyName>
        </ogc:Function>
    </Geometry>  
    <Fill>
        <GraphicFill>
            <Graphic>
                <Mark>
                    <WellKnownName>shape://horline</WellKnownName>
                    <Stroke>
                        <CssParameter name="stroke">
                            <ogc:PropertyName>COLOR</ogc:PropertyName>
                        </CssParameter>
                        <CssParameter name="stroke-width">2.5</CssParameter>
                    </Stroke>
                </Mark>
                <Rotation>Nagib</Rotation>
            </Graphic>
        </GraphicFill>
    </Fill>
</PolygonSymbolizer>
```

**Update**

I've fixed the [bug](https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOT-5878?) now you will get no image drawn instead of the exception.

Comment: I edited the question with the 'problem' I get when using rotated horline. Maybe it is better to post that as a new question, to keep it easier to track, but I am not sure.

Comment: that is probably a new question