# SLD - break in hatch

Tags: geoserver, style, sld, geotools

When I use rotated horline or vertline like @Ian Turton suggested in his answer to question [Rendering sld style(buffer) SEVERE null java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/262200/rendering-sld-stylebuffer-severe-null-java-lang-negativearraysizeexception/262342?noredirect=1#comment415976_262342), then I get breaks in the hatch, like on the image below. I can't find a way to get hatch without break. This hatch is rotated to the basis of an object by 45 degrees (so I can't use shape://slash), with different angles it looks even worse.

[image: break in hatch]

SLD suggested by @Ian

```
<PolygonSymbolizer>
<Geometry>
    <ogc:Function name="buffer">
        <ogc:PropertyName>the_geom</ogc:PropertyName>
        <ogc:PropertyName>Buffer</ogc:PropertyName>
    </ogc:Function>
</Geometry>  
<Fill>
    <GraphicFill>
        <Graphic>
            <Mark>
                <WellKnownName>shape://horline</WellKnownName>
                <Stroke>
                    <CssParameter name="stroke">
                        <ogc:PropertyName>COLOR</ogc:PropertyName>
                    </CssParameter>
                    <CssParameter name="stroke-width">2.5</CssParameter>
                </Stroke>
            </Mark>
            <Rotation>Nagib</Rotation>
        </Graphic>
    </GraphicFill>
</Fill>
```

Answer (score 5):

The solution is to use something similar to something you already used in the past (for reference [Using Math in SLD file - wkt](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/230810/using-math-in-sld-file-wkt)),

```
<PolygonSymbolizer>
    <Fill>
        <GraphicFill>
            <Graphic>
                <Mark>
                    <WellKnownName>wkt://LINESTRING(${cos(Nagib)*-20} ${sin(Nagib)*-20}, ${cos(Nagib)*20} ${sin(Nagib)*20} )</WellKnownName>
                    <Stroke>
                        <CssParameter name="stroke-width">1</CssParameter>
                    </Stroke>
                </Mark>
            </Graphic>
        </GraphicFill>
    </Fill>   
</PolygonSymbolizer>
```

[image: angle 32]
[image: angle 14]

For future users angles need to be specified in radians.

Answer (score 1):

For the staircase look, when you render the layer, make sure to have [anti-alliasing](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wms/vendor.html) enabled.

For the "dotted line" look, you could get closer to a continuous line by using a `wkt://MULTILINESTRING` graphic fill. You would create one by setting the default angle, that you can further rotate. To achieve the continuous look, you would expand the line beyond coordinate 1 (any direction). Depending on the rotation you have to apply, you may want to to add rules and change the initial line coordinates.

Let's not forget that the symbol is repeated every 1 unit (grid of symbol) and the rotation applies to each symbol, so while you could manage to connect the lines between 2 adjacent symbol, the spacing between two lines will be affected and not constant.

Here is the relevant part of the SLD for the following screenshot. The initial symbol is angled at  45 degrees, on which I have applied a 10 degrees rotation

```
 <GraphicFill>
        <Graphic>
            <Mark>
                <WellKnownName>wkt://MULTILINESTRING((-1.5 -1.5,1.5 1.5))</WellKnownName>
                <Stroke>
                    <CssParameter name="stroke-width">1</CssParameter>
                </Stroke>
            </Mark>
            <Rotation>10</Rotation>
        </Graphic>
    </GraphicFill>
```

[image]

If you have no extra rotation (0), here is the default output (45 deg)

[image]

Comment: It only changes the quality of displayed graphics, doesn't fix the hatch problem.

Comment: @Zole95 ok, here is an edit for the other interpretation of the issue

Comment: Problem is bunch of possible rotations in one file, this is your style with rotation of 32
https://image.prntscr.com/image/-Y245ho7Rr6HvMPoIZu1rw.png